# Updating records in model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I try update model in database. 
I have request with naw values and value.

'old_log'- old value to find row in database.

```
 public function UserChange2(Request $request){
        dump($request);
        $data=$request->all();
        $log = $request->input('old_log');
    dump($log);
$user=userModel::select(['fam','im','ot','phone','log','pass'])->where('log',$log)->first();
    $temp=$request->input('fam');
   $user->fam=$temp;
    $temp=$request->input('im');
    $user->im=$temp;
    $temp=$request->input('ot');
    $user->ot=$temp;
    $temp=$request->input('phone');
    $user->phone=$temp;
    $temp=$request->input('log2');
    $user->log=$temp;
    $temp=$request->input('pass');
    $user->pass=$temp;
    dump($user);
    $user->save;
}
```

But the records in the table are not updated.

Model:

```
class userModel extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable=['fam','im','ot','phone','log','pass','reg','token','date','position'];

}
```

Now:

```
   dump($request);
        $data=$request->all();
        $log = $request->input('old_log');
    dump($log);
  $user=userModel::select(['fam','im','ot','phone','log','pass'])->where('log',$log)->first();
           $user->fill($request->all())->save();
        $user->save;
```

And error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `user_models` set `fam` = y, `phone` = gggg, `pass` = tttyyyyyyyy where `id` is null)

Comment: What do you have for $fillable in your model ?
Also, you could do `$user->fill($request->all())->save()` instead of all the assignation

Comment: ' public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable=['fam','im','ot','phone','log','pass','reg','token','date','position'];'

Answer (score 1):

Your `userModel` extends `Model`, which is an Eloquent Model and by default expects that the related table has a primary key called `id`.

The error

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'

indicates that the column `id` does not exist.

Check your table definition. Is this a table in a DB that was created outside your Laravel project?

If not, check your database migration whether the primary key `id` is defined. Read [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations) about database migrations.

If there is already a primary key that you want to use instead of `id`, you can tell Eloquent:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'your_primary_key';
```

See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent).

Answer (score 0):

You likely don't have fillables completed in your Model.
Go to the model which should be blank and add the fields that can be completed:

example:

```
    protected $fillable = [
    'phone', 'log2', 'pass',    
];
```

You can find this in the Laravel manual here:
[https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#mass-assignment](http://Laravel%205.5%20Fillable%20-%20Mass%20Assignment)

Answer (score 0):

remove select from your eloquent. try this..

```
$user=userModel::where('log',$log)->first();
$user::create($request->all());
```

edit

```
$user=userModel::where('log',$log)->first();
$request->request->add(['log' => $request->log2]);
$user::create($request->all());
```

Comment: I can not $request->all(). In my request there are old valur login, to find object in database.